# Vimeo's widget hubnut non-Flash alternative?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, gallery, carousel

i need to find or implement a javascript carrousel with html5 (probably youtube's video inside iframe)

similar to vimeo's hubnut: http://vimeo.com/widget (first widget. sorry that you need to log in; if you can't/don't want to login: there is one in the bottom right of this http://vimeo.com/api page)

[image]

Do you know any alternative that **doesn't make use of flash**? it doesn't matter if is not free,

Comment: http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2011/06/jquery-carousel.html

Comment: thanks, actually i've seen about 300 already but not many of them will let me put videos without re-coding it for complete... i'll make some tests with http://www.bkosborne.com/jquery-waterwheel-carousel